# Channels: why message is send at the end of processing

Tags: django, django-channels, channel

why using sync function `get_channel_layer().send()`, message is send at the end of processing

```py
def external_send(channel_name, data):
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    send_sync = async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)
    send_sync(
        channel_name,
        {
            "type": "send_json",
            "message": {"datetime": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(), **data},
        },
    )
```

using `self.send()` in consumer work as expected

here is my consumer class for testing purpose:

```py
class TestConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass

    def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        logger.debug(f"RECEIVE {content}")
        self.send_json(
            {
                "id": 1,
                "text": "Before sleep: self.send_json",
                "datetime": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
            }
        )
        external_send(
            self.channel_name, {"id": 2, "text": "Before sleep external_send"}
        )
        sleep(10)  # Simuleting long processing
        self.send_json(
            {
                "id": 3,
                "text": "After sleep: self.send_json",
                "datetime": datetime.datetime.now().isoformat(),
            }
        )
        super().receive_json(content, **kwargs)
        logger.debug("END")
```

At frontend I'm receiving order

- {id: 1, text: "Before sleep: self.send_json", datetime: "2020-05-29T14:30:58.226545"}
- {id: 3, text: "After sleep: self.send_json", datetime: "2020-05-29T14:31:03.244865"}
- {id: 2, text: "Before sleep external_send", datetime: "2020-05-29T14:30:58.230164"}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In answer, each channel consumer gets its own little runloop. It will only handle one event at a time. This single runloop is used for both messages received from the client (over the ws) and messages being handled through group send events on the channel layers.

if you `receive_json` method you are sleeping that is sleeping the loop so nothing else will happen. `receive_json` needs to finish before any message sent over the channel layer will be handled.

## Looking at your code there are a few other points that need to be pointed out

### Sync `sleep`

If you do need to `sleep` in a method **never** do that in a sync method, this will sleep your **entier** python program (everything will sleep).

Use the Async consumer then you can `await asyncio.sleep(20)` this will then just `sleep` your runloop for that single consumer and other websocket connections etc will continue to run. This is also true for any other long running task you should use a async consumer and then use a async threadpool  to `await` these long running tasks.

### You should not attempt to group send to the `send_json` method directly.

Intread you should create a method on your consumer `handle_message` this method can call `send_json` and your group sends should send messages with type `handle.message`.

Comment: in this example `sleep` is just simulation of synchronous python code like DB read/write etc. Can't use async right now.